# How to test custom hook?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

My custom hook:

```
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../app/redux";
import { registrationFormSlice } from "../../entities/registration";

export interface IgetFields {
  label: string;
  valueKey: string;
  setValue: any;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export const useFields = (): (() => IgetFields[][]) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const { setEmail } =
    registrationFormSlice.actions;

  const getFields = (): IgetFields[][] => {
    return [
      [
        {
          label: "Email",
          valueKey: "email",
          setValue: (value: string) =>
            dispatch(setEmail({value, error:false, text:''})),
        },
      ],
    ];
  };
  return getFields;
};
```

My reducer:

```
import { initialState } from "./initialState";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IRegistrationState } from "./models";

export const registrationFormSlice = createSlice({
  name: "registrationForm",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
  
    setEmail(
      state: IRegistrationState,
      action: PayloadAction<{ value: string; error: boolean; text: string }>
    ) {
      state.data.email.value = action.payload.value;
      state.data.email.error = action.payload.error;
      state.data.email.errorText = action.payload.text;
    },
  },
});
```

My Store:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { registrationFormSlice } from "./registration";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  registrationForm: registrationFormSlice.reducer,
});

export const setupStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  });
};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"];
```

My test:

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useFields } from "./data";
import * as useAppDispatch from "../../app/redux";

describe("useFields", () => {
  const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(useAppDispatch, "useAppDispatch");
  useDispatchMock.mockReturnValue(jest.fn());

  const setup = () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFields());

    return result.current();
  };

  it("Must be an array of arrays", () => {
    const getFields = setup();

    expect(Array.isArray(getFields)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(useDispatchMock).toBeCalled();
  });

  it("An array with index 0 must have certain properties and structure", () => {
    const getFields = setup()[0];

    expect(getFields.length).toBe(1);
    expect(typeof getFields[0].label).toBe("string");
    expect(getFields[0].valueKey).toBe("email");
    expect(typeof getFields[0].setValue).toBe("function");
  });
});
```

Everything works, the test passes, I don't like only the test coverage:

[image]

**I do not know how to test this line of code**

I tried to check with which argument my useDispatchMock is called:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { useFields } from './data';
import { setupStore } from '../../entities/store';


describe('useFields', () => {
  const store = setupStore();
  
  const setup = () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(useFields, {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>,
    });
    return result.current();
  };

  it('Must be an array of arrays', () => {
    const getFields = setup();
    expect(Array.isArray(getFields)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('An array with index 0 must have certain properties and structure', () => {
    const getFields = setup()[0];
    expect(getFields).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(getFields[0]).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        label: expect.any(String),
        valueKey: expect.any(String),
        setValue: expect.any(Function),
      })
    );
  });

  test('should set email value correctly', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const getFields = setup()[0];
    const firstField = getFields[0];
    store.subscribe(() => {
      expect(store.getState().regsitration.data).toEqual({
        email: {
          value: 'test@example.com',
          error: false,
          errorText: '',
        },
      });
    });
    firstField.setValue('test@example.com');
  });
});
```

But I got an error:

[image]

Is my approach a bad one? What can I do to get rid of this issue? Any suggestion, link and information is welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mock `useAppDispatch` which is a hook use the `useDispatch` hook from the `react-redux` package. An incorrect mock will break its original implementation. Instead, we can provide a mock store and test if the redux actions are dispatched and redux state is updated correctly.

E.g.

`registration.ts`:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type IRegistrationState = {
  data: {
    email: {
      value: string;
      error: boolean;
      errorText: string | null;
    };
  };
};

export const registrationFormSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'registrationForm',
  initialState: {
    data: {
      email: {
        value: '',
        error: false,
        errorText: null,
      },
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    setEmail(state: IRegistrationState, action: PayloadAction<{ value: string; error: boolean; text: string }>) {
      state.data.email.value = action.payload.value;
      state.data.email.error = action.payload.error;
      state.data.email.errorText = action.payload.text;
    },
  },
});
```

`store.ts`:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { registrationFormSlice } from './registration';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  registrationForm: registrationFormSlice.reducer,
});

export const setupStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  });
};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
```

`useFields.ts`:

```
import { useAppDispatch } from './store';
import { registrationFormSlice } from './registration';

export interface IgetFields {
  label: string;
  valueKey: string;
  setValue: any;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export const useFields = (): (() => IgetFields[][]) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const { setEmail } = registrationFormSlice.actions;

  const getFields = (): IgetFields[][] => {
    return [
      [
        {
          label: 'Email',
          valueKey: 'email',
          setValue: (value: string) => dispatch(setEmail({ value, error: false, text: '' })),
        },
      ],
    ];
  };
  return getFields;
};
```

`useFields.test.tsx`:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { setupStore } from './store';
import { useFields } from './useFields';

describe('useFields', () => {
  const store = setupStore();
  const setup = () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(useFields, {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>,
    });
    return result.current();
  };

  it('Must be an array of arrays', () => {
    const getFields = setup();
    expect(Array.isArray(getFields)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('An array with index 0 must have certain properties and structure', () => {
    const getFields = setup()[0];
    expect(getFields).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(getFields[0]).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        label: expect.any(String),
        valueKey: expect.any(String),
        setValue: expect.any(Function),
      })
    );
  });

  test('should set email value correctly', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const getFields = setup()[0];
    const firstField = getFields[0];
    store.subscribe(() => {
      expect(store.getState().registrationForm.data).toEqual({
        email: {
          value: 'test@example.com',
          error: false,
          errorText: '',
        },
      });
    });
    firstField.setValue('test@example.com');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76031614/useFields.test.tsx (7.997 s)
  useFields
    ✓ Must be an array of arrays (14 ms)
    ✓ An array with index 0 must have certain properties and structure (3 ms)
    ✓ should set email value correctly (4 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 registration.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 store.ts        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useFields.ts    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.462 s, estimated 10 s
```